# Decoding JSON from file in PHP

Tags: php, json, file, encoding

```
if (($json=file_get_contents($_FILES["file_upload"]["tmp_name"]))) {
    //$json='{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
    $content=json_decode($json,TRUE);
                  }
```

I upload a file and then read it in PHP. THe problem I get NULL returned from json_decode, the json is valid though, because when I try to decode the same JSON from a string it decodes fine. Any ideas what might be wrong.

I have figured out that I get three � at the beggining of the string. So I do a substr for now, but what is this?

Comment: do `echo $json` to verify it's reading the file properly

Comment: are you sure the JSON is properly formatted?, if it's not, json_decode will return null.

Comment: It is properly formatted because I try the Json in a string and it works. The file is read properly to.

Comment: Is the json file is in unicode format?

Comment: have you checked why `json_decode()` failed? You can use [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to find out more information about the error.

Comment: The json_last_error() outputs 4

Comment: which is JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX

Comment: Just post the `bin2hex($json)`

Comment: efbbbf7b2261223a312c2262223a322c2263223a332c2264223a342c2265223a357d this is the output to bin2hex

Answer (score 0):

Add below code on the top of your PHP file, which is generating JSON.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```